ChromeDriver for Chrome version 125 macOS
I have found that the ChromeDriver existed for the Google version 114. But now my Chrome is already updated to version 125 and I cannot find the direct version of ChromeDriver for my macOS. Does anyone please help me, ThankYou. Ps. I want to use it with selenium.
I have tried to find the direct version for my macOS.

If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, you can get all the drivers from Chrome for Testing availability

Link to download latest stable chrome driver

Link to download chrome driver version 125 for mac-arm64

Link to download chrome driver version 125 for mac-x64



The built-in Selenium Manager means that the correct chromedriver version is automatically downloaded as needed. Eg. Python:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...
driver.quit()

With customization options:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()

It has been available since November 2022: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/
